# Floating div is escaping parent div

Tags: html, css

I set a width & height to the parent images div. There are two child divs inside of it called image_one and image_two with a set width. The problem is that when I reduce the width of the viewport, the image_two div escapes the parent div and comes under the image_one div. How do I keep this div from escaping? I figured that setting a percentage width would automatically resize the div to stay inside of the parent div. When I set an overflow:hidden, both of the divs disappear.

Here is a link to the code:

http://codepen.io/matosmtz/pen/ZGpNmy

```
<div class="images">
    <div class="image_one">
        <p style="background-color:red; text-align:center">Photo</p>  
    </div>
    <div class="image_two">
        <p style="background-color:red; text-align:center">Photo</p>  
    </div>       
</div>


.images {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 220px;
}

.image_one {
    width: 30%;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: black;
    padding: 5px;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
}

.image_two {
    width: 30%;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: black;
    padding: 5px;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

Comment: I think your parent should also have a position: relative or position: absolute;

Comment: Adding overflow hidden clears the floats, and the `.images` div slides below the sidebar, since the sidebar is 200px wide and `.images` is 100% wide so there is no enough space for both divs.

Comment: I can't set a position absolute because I want the parent to be relative to the side_nav and to the header. I tried setting a position: relative but the child divs are still escaping the parent div.

Comment: @SlavenkoMiljic ohhh ok, I figured that setting a width to 100%  for the images div would only use the remainder space that is on the right of the side_nav. I guess that It's using 100% of the entire viewport width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.images` div is 100% width. This includes the sidebar on your codepen.

The child divs are 30%, but this means 30% of the whole space. So when you reduce the size of the browser, eventually they are big enough to need to slide under one another, because your `.sidebar` has a fixed width of 200px.

I would suggest having a look at how the [Bootstrap CSS](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) works in order to find your fix for this, or straight out using that.

Comment: Hi, yeah @SlavenkoMijic mentioned this a couple minutes ago. I will look into how Bootstrap works. One of the reasons I'm not using Bootstrap is because I want to be able able to code my entire portfolio website. I feel that this will allow me to learn more about coding. Do you have any other suggestions that my help me learn how to code a website?

Comment: I think the main thrust of your problem here would probably be helped by learning about media queries. Bootstrap grids work so well in part because they use media queries to say things like "when the browser window is over x pixels wide, this element is y pixels wide" and so on. They take a form like `@media (min-width: 992px) { [embed rules about elements here] }` meaning: once the browser is over the min-width of 992px, do the following. They're super useful for creating a nice, responsive site.